# Convert u128 to Vec<u8> and string to Vec<u8>

Tags: substrate

How can I convert u128 to Vec<u8> (bytes) and string to Vec<u8> in substrate?

```
pub fn add_profile_fund(origin: OriginFor<T>, citizenid: u128) -> DispatchResult {
// convert citizen id to Vec<u8> 
// convert "profile_fund" string to Vec<u8>
// Then concatenate the two Vec using push.
```

Comment: Type conversion is giving a lot of trouble in substrate as std is not supported

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to encode them to u8 then scale encoding will likely be what you are after: https://github.com/paritytech/parity-scale-codec

There's documentation on it here:
https://docs.substrate.io/v3/advanced/scale-codec/

Comment: Gives error for importing in substrate 4.0.0.   no matching package named `parity_scale_codec` found
location searched: https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git?tag=monthly-2021-10
required by package `pallet-template v3.0.0-monthly-2021-10

Comment: replace the underscores with hyphens. Almost all the substrate crates have the convention that it is hyphens in crate names and underscores in the code. https://github.com/paritytech/parity-scale-codec/blob/94f5887207af4abfb85e266985f9bd260ee09e04/Cargo.toml#L2